# How to send mail with Attachment file

Tags: asp.net, sendmail

I am trying to send mail with attache a file (.docx or .pdf) and I successfully done this. But when I am trying to download the attached file from receiver mail id then the .docx file is open as blank document and .pdf file is corrupted. I am not able to understand what is happening here.
My code is given below.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("mail.360google.in");

                mail.From = new MailAddress("sender@360google.in");
                mail.To.Add("receiver@gmail.com");
                mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
                mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FUResume.PostedFile.FileName);
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FUResume.PostedFile.InputStream, FileName));

                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sender@360google.in", "mypassword");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)  { return true; };

                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Please any one tell me what king of problem occurring here and give me correct code for this.

Comment: Do you have this code inside Ajax control?

Comment: No I have not used any kind of Ajax control.

Comment: Have you tried peeking length of `FUResume.PostedFile.InputStream.Length` while debugging, it must be non zero value for a valid file with data.